# How to convert nvarchar formatted as '0.25' to a negative decimal in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a value in a database `nvarchar` formatted as  '0.25-'. I need advice on how to convert this to a -0.25 decimal value in a query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use case statement to check the value with '-' at the end and then convert to decimal and multiply that value with (-1) to make -ve.

```
Declare @tempTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))  
Insert Into @tempTable Values 
('0.00')
,('1.00')
,('2.75-')


Select SomeCol, 
CASE 
    WHEN CHARINDEX('-', SomeCol)>0 
        THEN (-1)*CAST(replace(SomeCol,'-','') AS DECIMAL(10,2)) 
        ELSE CAST(SomeCol AS DECIMAL(10,2)) END  DECIMAL_VAL    
From  @tempTable
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just another option

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('0.25-')
,('0.50')
,('0.00')


Select SomeCol
      ,AsDecimal = try_convert(decimal(10,2),replace(SomeCol,'-',''))*sign(right(SomeCol,1)+'99')
 From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
SomeCol AsDecimal
0.25-   -0.25
0.50    0.5
0.00    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @John Cappelletti, for sample data.

you can flip the negative sign to beginning and convert to decimal(3,2), as given below:

```sql
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] nvarchar(50))  

Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('0.25-')
,('0.50')
,('0.00')

SELECT Somecol, 
CASE WHEN RIGHT(SomeCol,1)  = N'-' 
     THEN CAST(CONCAT('-',LEFT(SomeCol,LEN(Somecol)-1)) AS DECIMAL(3,2)) 
     ELSE CAST(Somecol AS DECIMAL(3,2)) 
     END AS SomeCol_modified
from @YourTable
```

| Somecol | SomeCol_modified |
| --- | --- |
| 0.25- | -0.25 |
| 0.50 | 0.50 |
| 0.00 | 0.00 |